Load Balancer Registered target group are showing status as Initial/Unhealthy and giving 502 Bad Gateway and 504 gateway timeout error
Problem statement: Target group is showing health status as Initial and website is giving 502 Bad Gateway and 504 gateway timeout error (It is happening intermittently). But if I re-registered the same target group manually, website works fine.
How to reproduce?
I have a deployment file (ex: aws.yml), which is containing a job to register a container IP in ELB Fargate.
Here is the sample configuration:
name: Register Container IP in ELB Fargate
id: register-ip
env:
  ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
  AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN: ${{ inputs.AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN }}
run: |
  echo "ECS_CLUSTER: $ECS_CLUSTER"
  echo "AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN: $AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN"
      
  aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER
  TASK_ARN=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER --query "taskArns[0]" --output text)
  echo "TASK_ARN: $TASK_ARN"
      
  aws ecs describe-tasks --tasks "$TASK_ARN" --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER
  TASK_IP=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --tasks "$TASK_ARN" --cluster $ECS_CLUSTER --query "tasks[0].containers[0].networkInterfaces[0].privateIpv4Address" --output text)
  echo "TASK_IP: $TASK_IP"
      
  aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn "$AWS_TARGET_GROUP_ARN" --targets Id=$TASK_IP,Port=3000  

This job runs successfully and also register the newly generated TASK_IP in load balancer under registered targets in  target groups. But as I mentioned earlier Health status is showing “Initial” and site is not loading up. But if I re-registered the same target group manually, website works fine.
Here is the health check settings of EC2 -> Target Groups -> <Target Group Name>:

This is the registered target screenshot:

And here is the load balancer mapping screenshot :

How can I resolve this issue?
Update
I am able to fix the health status issue by updating the heath check settings to this.

Now health status is showing as Healthy for the new registered IP.
Latest problem statement :
Whenever a new task IP is registered by the new deployment in the ELB Fargate target groups, the old running task IP immediately goes into an unhealthy state. A new task IP is then assigned, which takes a few minutes to become healthy.
The issue is that during the time it takes for the new IP to become healthy, the website experiences downtime and shows 502 and 504 errors.
This is my portMappings and networkMode setting in task definition:
{
  ...
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  ...
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "XXXXX",
      ...
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
      ... 
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ]
  ...
}

Is there a way to achieve zero downtime during this transition, ensuring that the website does not show these errors while the new IP is becoming healthy?

Why are you deploying your ECS tasks this way, instead of using an ECS Service? An ECS Service would deploy the tasks for you, and register them with the load balancer's target group automatically.

@MarkB - As per my organization standard we have to strictly use GitHub actions for the deployment of the code from GitHub repo to AWS ECS. That’s the reason I am following the same approach. Can you please help me in finding the root cause of this issue. I am stuck on it from past 2 days.

GitHub actions can deploy ECS services... That requirement does not, in any way, restrict you from using ECS the correct way. Without using ECS services, if your task were to crash for some reason, it will not be redeployed automatically by ECS, and you have to do all this manual stuff to register your task with the load balancer, instead of letting ECS do that for you automatically.

@MarkB I got this use case and yeah its a major one. Thanks for pointing this out. Can you please help me what correction I have to made to make it work. I am from frontend background so trying this for first time in my current project.
FYI, The configuration which i added in my post is just one job, I can see that we are using ECS Service and we are using that in this job Deploy Amazon ECS task definition

If you have a single task per registered target it makes sense that you get some 502/504 errors while updating your task, since it cannot run and update at the same time. To make sure this is your issue, you could try to perform some requests while updating, you should not get any 200.
To overcome this you probably want to deploy via an ECS service as stated by Mark B and use rolling deployment. This will allow you to always have a running instance even during deployment.


Select Target Group into Load Balancer and Verify health check settings
path: Verify the path matches the endpoint that should respond with a 200 OK status
Timeout and Interval : Adjust it according to the container start time because if you having heavy applications or container size more then uptime of the container also more like 90 Seconds or more in that case of health check happening it definitely return 500 or 504 Errors
Change the Threshold value based on  your Application behaviour
Also review the load balancer listener configuration and Routing rules and conditions to ensure that no conflict in it.
We faced similar issues with ECS fargate we set the alert. We have to restart the task or delete the current running container to resolve the transient issues

